# Detect if php script has been requested by <img> parsing

Tags: php, image, request, src

I have a file manager website running and some users said they'd like to be able to embed the image preview page directly into img tags (on forums etc).

Lets take this page as an example: http://push.anukthewolf.com/a/Screenshot_2015-06-03-08-29-03.png

Even though it has an image extension, it's still a html (well, php) page. Could this script somehow detect if its requesting client is a browser parsing an img tag where its url has been used as source?
If that's the case I would output the image directly instead of the website. In every other case, the website should be sent.

Comment: Well you could if you added for example a GET parameter flag to say whether to return a page or image.

Comment: Is there any other way than that? I'd really like to let the url's stay as they are. All of the users already used lots of url's somewhere and it would be bad if all of these won't work anymore/as expected

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/6882437/2078771

Comment: Thanks for the link, after some fiddling this works perfectly!